# Is there a way to count how many values I have in yield?

Tags: python, yield

I am wondering is there way to find out how many pair values(start, end) before I create a new `file.txt`.  My goal here is to check if I start, end value more than one pair then I want to create separate file for each pair.  If not then just leave it as is.

```
def searchPFAM(fname):
    with open(fname,'rb') as f:
        root = etree.parse(f)
        for lcn in root.xpath("/protein/match[@dbname='PFAM']/lcn"):#find dbname =PFAM
            try:
                start = int(lcn.get("start"))#if it is PFAM then look for start value
                end = int(lcn.get("end"))#if it is PFAM then also look for end value
                yield start, end
            except (TypeError , ValueError) as e:
                pass 

with open('newfile.txt','w') as fileinput:
    for start, end in searchPFAM(fname):
        print start, end  
        if start <= end:
            text=''.join(makeList[(start-1):(end-1)])
            fileinput.write(text)
```

Comment: no you can't do that with `yield`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a file for each pair you can do something like this:

```
for i, (start, end) in enumerate(searchPFAM(fname)):
    print start, end  
    if start <= end:
        with open('newfile-%s.txt' % i,'w') as fileinput:
            text=''.join(makeList[(start-1):(end-1)])
            fileinput.write(text)
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I had no idea you could unpack nested tuples like that. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way to do that.  You could just return a list of objects and get it's length (or easier, cast the return value to a list):

```
PFAMresults=list(searchPFAM)
nresults=len(PFAMresults)
for start,end in PFAMresults:
    dosomething()
```

Comment: More easily done by `blah = list(searchPFAM())` than modifying the behaviour of the function